# ¿Por qué el icono de Stack Overflow en español es diferente según el lugar?

Tags: discusión, bug

El icono de Stack Overflow en español es amarillo en el menú de Stack Exchange y en las pestañas del navegador. Sin embargo, el logotipo de la página principal es el mismo que en Stack Overflow.

Aquí unas fotos:

- **En las pestañas del navegador**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- **En el menú de StackExchange**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- **En la página principal**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿No tendría que ser el mismo en todos los sitios? Creo que este puede ser uno de los motivos por los que la gente se confunde y escribe las preguntas en inglés confundiendo el sitio Stack Overflow en español con la versión inglesa Stack Overflow y las cuales muestran el mismo logo en la página principal (aunque el texto sea distinto).

¿Es un fallo o está hecho a propósito?

Comment: Y entrando desde movil sale el icono azul de StackExchange en lugar del amarillo de SOes

Comment: Esto también ocurre con los otros [so] en otros idiomas: [pt.so], [ru.so] y [ja.so]. Entiendo que se hace para mantener consistencia y que todo el mundo sepa que al fin y al cabo es Stack Overflow, solo que en otro idioma.

Comment: @fedorqui Sí, yo también he pensado que sería para no perder consistencia pero no estaba seguro de si era un bug o no. Si está en los de otros idiomas entonces entiendo que no lo será. Sin embargo, lo veo confuso y de hecho yo algunas veces tengo que mirar fijamente si estoy en el de inglés o en el de español (realmente por eso me he dado cuenta de que era el mismo icono).

Comment: Lo que dije yo del icono azul de StackExchange tiene sentido porque en realidad es el menú de StackExchange. Como en el móvil está junto al nombre de del sitio _Stackoverflow en español_ pensé que el icono estaba mal pero es así en todas las páginas de StackExchange.